# Dynamically assign variables to items in for loop from beautiful soup

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I'm webscraping some content with Beautiful Soup, I'm returning three items in my script and want to assign the values to variables.

```
for categories in item_soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'breadcrumbs'}):
    for categories in categories.find_all('a', {'title': ''}):
        categories = categories.get_text()
        print(categories)
```

This returns:

```
category1
category2
category3
```

How can I assign individual variables to each category for later use? I've thought about using a [0:1] slicing technique but that returns sliced letters per value. I've tried to convert the items into a list or set, but no luck.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, you should use `list` for store all categories:

```
result = []    
for categories in item_soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'breadcrumbs'}).categories.find_all('a', {'title': ''}):
    categories = categories.get_text()
    result.append(categories)
```

Also, you can use `list comprehension` for it

Comment: Thanks, I'm seeing the error below when a try and print a specific value.

print(results[1]) 
IndexError: list index out of range

print(result[0]) will return the entire list, rather than first object.

Comment: Resolved: Some results only returned 1 object, so an Index Error for out of range was being generated in these instances. Added a try with index error expectation to resolve.